# Add custom action to the page listing screen

Tags: pages, actions, draft

I'm creating functionality that will clone a published page and create a new draft page from the content.  I placed an action link alongside the "Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View" items that appear beneath each page title on the page listing page within the admin dash.  My link has the post_id and the custom action name.  The link points back to the edit.php page and a function is run if the action matches clone-post_{post_id}.  I get the following error screen each time I click the link.  However, the clone functionality does work.  When I go back to the page listings page the draft page exists with the appropriate content.

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'update_page_listing_menu', 10, 2);
add_filter('page_row_actions', 'update_page_listing_menu', 10, 2);
function update_page_listing_menu($actions, WP_Post $post)
{
    $site_url = site_url();
    $base_url = $site_url .'/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&post=' . $post->ID . '&action=clone-post_'. $post->ID;

    $actions['clone-post'] = '<a href="'. $base_url . '">Copy to Draft</a>';
    return $actions;
}

// If copy to draft is true in the query vars then copy the post
add_action('wp_loaded','check_for_clone_action');
function check_for_clone_action() {
    if ( strpos($_REQUEST['action'],'clone-post_' ) !== false )
        create_draft_post_from_published_post($_REQUEST['post']);
}

function create_draft_post_from_published_post($id)
{

        $current_post = get_post( $id );

        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title'   => $current_post->post_title,
            'post_content' => $current_post->post_content,
            'meta_input'   => array(
                'published_post_id' => $id
            ),
            'post_type'    => 'page'

        ), true );

}
```

FYI:  I will add nonce verification once I get this working.

Below is the page that I see when clicking the link:
[image: Page after clicking]

Comment: What is the `$complete_url`? Where is it defined? And in your `check_for_clone_action()`, you should redirect (back to the edit page) and `exit`..

Comment: I'm sorry.  That had to do with me creating a nonce. I've updated the code.  Where it said $complete_url it's now $base_url as it should be.  I realized that the issue occurs when I make the URL poing to edit.php?{queryvars}.  I changed that to {domain}/wp-admin/index.php and that allows the functions to run, doesn't give me the error and then at the end of the check_for_clone_action() (as you said) I redirect to the edit page of the newly created draft post.

Is there a better way to do this than to point to wp-admin/index.php instead?

Comment: It's fine to link to `wp-admin/edit.php`. You can also link to `wp-admin/admin.php`. Just make sure you redirect after the post is cloned. (to avoid issues like one shown in the image) But if you use a *static* action name like `clone-post` and not `clone-post_<post ID>`, then you can simply hook to `admin_action_clone-post` and no need for the `strpos()` check in your function.. :)

Comment: Awesome Thanks!

Comment: FYI: Even after redirecting in check_for_clone_action() I still received the error.  Changing my `$base_url` to be `$site_url .'/wp-admin/index.php?post_type=page&post=' . $post->ID . '&action=clone-post_'. $post->ID;` did the trick.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, but [this](https://gist.github.com/5ally/4a1b3f0c571438d4c2bf3ec0d02efc5c#file-using-wp_loaded-php) is what I meant, tried and it worked well for me.